# Custom DetermineChannelProcessor not firing

Tags: xdb

I have created a custom `DetermineChannelProcessor` which inherits `DetermineChannelProcessorBase` and can confirm it is registered in the correct section of the configuration using the `showconfig.aspx`. However it doesn't seem to fire. I have `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` both set to true. As well as the "`VisitorIdentification`" snippet in my pages.

Version of Sitecore is v9.0 Update-2.

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Hi Sam! Welcome to Sitecore StackExchange.  I would consider adding code snippets of your custom proessor to help others understand what you are doing your question in order to get more people involved with helping your exact situation.

Comment: Please also show us your config where the custom processor is registered. The order of processors in the pipeline `<determineInteractionChannel>` is important, so you may move your customer processor to be the last in the pipeline to override standard Sitecore logic.